# How can I avoid a thread block when reading a full TCPStream in Rust for my HTTP webserver?

Tags: http, rust

I am new to Rust and currently writing an HTTP-Webserver as a learning project whilst trying not to use any external libraries. Currently, I'm struggling with a problem of reading in a full TCPStream to read the data of requests with a body.

My current approach is similar to the one provided in the Rust Book:

```rust
let buf_reader = Bufreader::new(&stream);
let http_request = buf_reader
    .lines()
    .map(|line| line.unwrap())
    .take_while(|line| !line.is_empty())
    .collect::<Vec<String>>();
```

But when I try to remove the `take_while` it hangs up the thread and if I try to reload the connection from Firefox I get an unwrap on an `Err` value.

If possible, I'd like to avoid reading the full http request regardless of its size. I tried setting the stream to nonblocking, but that didn't work.

Comment: The Rust community has largely coalesced around using [Tokio](https://tokio.rs) to solve problems like this, so I'd encourage you to do the same. The async patterns expressed in there are quite different and involve `await`. That avoids a block using a scheduler, and other async-specific details.

Comment: The community is great, and don't forget about the [Discord group](https://discord.com/invite/tokio) where questions like this are more than welcome.

Comment: @tadman `tokio` is not related. You can perfectly build an HTTP server with blocking code. There are libraries like `hyper`, but the OP doesn't want to use external libraries.

Comment: You only read the first part of the request, the target and headers. You need to parse `Content-Length` and parse the body accordingly.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman wouldn't that be a security risk, if the client inputs a wrong data size?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Obviously you can write blocking code and it works fine, but it does block the thread. The alternative is lots of fussing with non-blocking reads, or just use async as in Tokio which gives you way more flexibility.

Comment: @tadman Sure, but as a learning experience, I'd go with blocking as it's easier and avoids a dependency.

Comment: @CodeCraft Surely this is a security risk. Implementing HTTP correctly and securely is very hard and nuanced. Even your code contains security risks (e.g. what if the client never closes the connection). If you want to use this server in a production system, don't implement HTTP by yourself - use a library like `hyper`. But as a learning matter it's fine.

Comment: Ok @ChayimFriedman thanks for the clarification. This code is in no way planned to be used in production. I just want to get under the hood of how things work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer without async/await, and correct me if there are vulnerabilities, is:

```rust
    let mut buf_reader = BufReader::new(&mut stream);
    let mut headers: Vec<String> = vec![];

    loop {
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        let _ = buf_reader.read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        if buffer == "\r\n" {
            break;
        }
        headers.push(buffer);
    }
```

```rust
    if request.can_have_body() {
        let length = if let Some(len) = request
            .headers
            .iter()
            .filter(|header| header.contains("Content-Length: "))
            .clone()
            .map(|header| {
                let header = header.strip_prefix("Content-Length: ").unwrap();
                header.trim().parse::<usize>()
            })
            .next()
        {
            if let Ok(size) = len {
                size
            } else {
                0
            }
        } else {
            0
        };
        let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = vec![0; length];
        let read_len = buf_reader.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        if read_len != length {
            eprintln!("User inputted invalid BUFLEN");
            return;
        }
    }
```

If I am wrong, i would be very thankful for correction or  improvement. Thank you. :-)